# Getting Edimax USB WiFi dongle to work

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, wireless-networking, usb

I have set up a clock-in kiosk for a local charity. For the past month, the kiosk has been working just fine. Recently, though, the wireless connection was acting up. I looked at the logs to see if there were any errors with the connection. AFAIK, there wasn't. Then I tried doing an update on the system. Apparently, that's made it worse. However, it doesn't look like the updates messed with the networking system (it updated packages like "dkms" and "unattended-upgrades").

What happens is that, while the dongle is recognized, it can't get an IP address. It still has the login information for the wireless network, though.

I am using an Edimax EW-7811Un wireless adapter with the "8192cu" kernel module. I installed it as per the [instructions](https://github.com/pvaret/rtl8192cu-fixes) on the "8192cu" github page. I've tried reinstalling it, but that hasn't worked. I have also tried blacklisting the "rtl8192cu" modules, with no change.

The kiosk is on an old Lenovo small ThinkCentre and uses Ubuntu 17.04 with the 4.10.0-38-generic kernel.

**Edit**: on the Ubuntu IRC channel someone thought that it could be a problem with `dhclient` trying to get an IP address and *then* the wifi adapter becomes available.

Comment: Long shot, but have you upgraded the kernel recently? If so, see if booting an older kernel gets you going.

Comment: I think I tried booting the 4.10.0-33-generic kennel (that was the previous kernel). But that didn't work.